# как передать класс в функцию через библиотеку schedule

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, schedule

Здраствуйте, недавно я начал использовать библиотеку schedule и хотел бы передать класс в функцию, но выводиться ошибка:

```
 self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

код у меня такой

```
def get_not(user:User):
        if user.notifation:
            price = get_btc()
            bot.send_message(chat_id = user.chat_id, text=price )

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_not(user))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да просто следом указать параметры. Как в доках написанно.

```
import schedule, time

def job(param1, param2):
    print(str(param1) + str(param2))



schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job,'do something', 'like this')
    
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```